# Molecular spectra

Tags: atomic-physics

In the case of molecular spectra, we say electron transition from one rotational(or vibrational) energy state of 'molecule' to another state. So, my question is where does this transition takes place exactly in space? Because for atoms we get the picture of orbitals as energy levels between which exactly transitions take place.

Comment: In the case of rotational spectra, the angular momentum of the molecule is quantized and can only vary by discrete steps. These steps have different energies and are considered as rotational states. I'm not too sure how to correlate with vibrations though.

Comment: Asking for 'where exactly' something takes place in quantum physics is doomed to failure. The molecule has extended orbitals and interactions. Transitions take place in that context.

Comment: @JonCuster: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the O2 molecule and you can imagine that both atoms are on either end of a spring, when the atoms begin to move in and out this would be a vibration but this vibration can only happen at certain frequencies (like a guitar string). You can think of the electrons as having their orbitals modified to slightly but discrete different energy levels.